# How to convert XML annotations [xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax] to tabula area?

Tags: data-extraction, tabula

We are using the retinanet object detector model to detect and extract data out of our tables. After using 1000+ image annotations we've got a good model. However, our issue arises when we want to extract the data. Most commonly used is Camelot but it is not working as well as we'd hope so we are trying to use tabula instead. When we use the XML annotations in the area parameter, it doesn't work. After looking around we saw that tabula only uses PDF point units. How can XML points be converted to PDF point units? Image detection below:

[Detected table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9vXS.png)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which units are used by retinanet.
A PDF point is defined as 1/72 of an inch, so you'll also need to know the resolution (in dots per inch) of your source images.

Bear in mind that Tabula does not work with raster (image) PDFs.

See: [Converting Pixels and Inches to PostScript Points](https://developers.foxitsoftware.com/kb/article/converting-pixels-and-inches-to-postscript-points/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, really appreciate it. We got our image dpi value with images.info['dpi'] which came out to be 200 (images which we created from the pdfs for detection). As you said, pdf point is 1/72 of an inch, we calculated the ratio to be 72/200 = 0.36 and then converted our x,y coordinates by multiplying by this factor and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Happy to help! By the way, I'm one of the maintainers of Tabula. We'd love to improve our table detection feature, so if your results can be shared, I'll be happy to talk :)